# Show Hibernate parameter binding

Tags: hibernate

Whenever i am inserting values the Hibernate log is showing

```
insert 
into
    FRIEND_JOB
    (COMPANY_NAME, PRIMARY_KEY) 
values
    (?, ?)
```

is there a way to show also the actual data which is inserted?

like :-

```
insert 
into
    FRIEND_JOB
    (COMPANY_NAME, PRIMARY_KEY) 
values
    (?, ?)
```

1:'xyz' and 2:1

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

With log4j you can easily increase log verbosity and show the actual parameter binding, for example see [this blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/) how to do this.

Comment: i did same thing whatever written on content, but did't worked.